# msg.sender not work parallel with metamask

Tags: metamask, web3.py, python, django

I am working with django project that is empowered with blockchain. I want to create an authentication system using blockchain technology. I write a smart contract and deploy it in ganache. In here I want to develop the registration access metamask cetain account. How I implement it. It means solidity `msg.sender` command should want to idintify the certain metamask account which user used.

**Smart contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract Auth{
    struct UserDetails {
        uint id;
        address UserAddress;
        string name;
        string email;
        string password;
        // string ipfsImageHash;
        bool isUserLoggedIn;
    }

    mapping(address => UserDetails) User;
    UserDetails[] public User_arr;
  
    address _address=msg.sender;

    constructor() public {
        
    }
    event RegNewUser(uint _id,string _name, string _email,string _password);
    event LogInUser(string _name, string _password);

    
    //get_address
    function get_address() public view returns(address){
        return _address;
    }
    // User registration function

    function registerUser(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _email,
        string memory _password
        // string memory _ipfsImageHash
    ) public returns (bool) {
        
        // require(User[_address].UserAddress != msg.sender);

        User[_address].UserAddress = _address;
        User[_address].name = _name;
        User[_address].email=_email;
        User[_address].password = _password;
        // User[_address].ipfsImageHash = _ipfsImageHash;
        User[_address].isUserLoggedIn = false;
        User[_address].id=User_arr.length;

        emit RegNewUser(
        User[_address].id,
        User[_address].name,
        User[_address].email,
        User[_address].password
        
        );
       User_arr.push(User[_address]);
        return true;
    }
```

**Python file**

```
import sys
from .auth_contract_connection import contract_address,abi
sys.path.append('../')
from connection import connection


auth_contract = connection.con.eth.contract(address = contract_address, abi = abi)
# addr=auth_contract.functions.get_address().call()
# print("address:",addr)
print(connection.con.eth.accounts[0])
# print(connection.con.eth.accounts[0])
def execTxn(txName,*args,**kwargs):
    # print(*args )
    return_value=None
    nonce =connection.con.eth.getTransactionCount(connection.wallet_address)
    print(nonce)
    buildData = {
        'from':connection.con.eth.accounts[1],
        'chainId': 4,
        'gas': 400000,
        'gasPrice': connection.con.toWei('40', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    }
    
    

    try:
        if (txName == 'registerUser'):
            txn_dict = auth_contract.functions.registerUser(*args).buildTransaction(buildData)
            return_value=auth_contract.functions.registerUser(*args).call()
            print(txn_dict)
    
   except Exception as e:
           print(e)
       if return_value!=None:
           return return_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `_address` to `msg.sender` when you define it. Therefore the value is set on deployment of the contract to the deployer and after that never updated.

If you want to have the `msg.sender` of the call to `registerUser` you need to read `msg.sender` inside this function.

A possible change could look this way:

```js
    function registerUser(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _email,
        string memory _password
        // string memory _ipfsImageHash
    ) public returns (bool) {
        
        // Get account that called this method
        address _address = msg.sender;

        // Check that the account is not already registered
        require(User[_address].UserAddress == address(0));

        User[_address].UserAddress = _address;
        User[_address].name = _name;
        User[_address].email=_email;
        User[_address].password = _password;
        // User[_address].ipfsImageHash = _ipfsImageHash;
        User[_address].isUserLoggedIn = false;
        User[_address].id=User_arr.length;

        emit RegNewUser(
            User[_address].id,
            User[_address].name,
            User[_address].email,
            User[_address].password
        );
        
        User_arr.push(User[_address]);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: yeah, that's right but metamask account does not recognize the system. That is a major problem?

Comment: You mean MetaMask is not decoding the transaction details?

Comment: @Richard Did you solve this problem?